# Why is my Android ListView selecting multiple items?

Tags: android, listview, android-arrayadapter

I'm making a simple ListView in Android which shows up as a dialog. It's purpose is for the user to select an item which will be saved as a SharedPreference. The next time the user opens up that same list, I want the item they selected last time to be highlighted.

My problem is that when I create the list using my ArrayAdapter, single out the index they selected last time, then apply a custom drawable as the background to show that item is currently saved, the ListView shows 3 items as "selected". It's always the first item, the last item, and the item that I want selected.

Here is an image showing what's going on

[image: image01][image: image02]

Here is the code for my ArrayAdapter. I am using the ViewHolder pattern.

```
public class AdapterColors extends ArrayAdapter<ColorItem> {
     private Context context;
     private ColorItem[] objects;
     private int layoutResource;

     private static class ViewHolder {
         ImageView icon;
         TextView color;
     }

     public AdapterColors(Context context, int resource, ColorItem[] objects) {
         super(context, resource, objects);
         this.context = context;
         this.layoutResource = resource;
         this.objects = objects;
     }

     @Override
     public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
         ColorItem colorItem = getItem(position);
         ViewHolder viewHolder;

         if (convertView == null) {
             viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
             LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
             convertView = inflater.inflate(layoutResource, parent, false);
             viewHolder.icon = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageview_icon);
             viewHolder.color = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textview_item_name);
             convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
         } else {
             viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
         }

         viewHolder.icon.setImageResource(colorItem.getColorIconId());
         viewHolder.color.setText(colorItem.getColorName());

         if(position == 2) {
             convertView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.list_item_selected);
         }

         return convertView;
     }
 }
```

R.drawable.list_item_selected is my custom drawable.

As a test, I'm only picking out the position of 2 as you can see in the getView() method. The item at position 2 properly gets its backgroundResource set, but the first and last items also get set! What is going on here!?

If anyone needs to see any other code, I'll be happy to update my question.

Thanks.

Comment: add else part for your if and set unselected background

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to give unselected image for all except position which you want as a selected in your case its position 2. Call `notifyDataSetChange` of `BaseAdapter` to refresh listview after clicking on ListItem or Selected item.

```
@Override
     public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
         ColorItem colorItem = getItem(position);
         ViewHolder viewHolder;

         if (convertView == null) {
             viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
             LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
             convertView = inflater.inflate(layoutResource, parent, false);
             viewHolder.icon = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageview_icon);
             viewHolder.color = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textview_item_name);
             convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
         } else {
             viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
         }

         viewHolder.icon.setImageResource(colorItem.getColorIconId());
         viewHolder.color.setText(colorItem.getColorName());
// need to give image for unselected state too.inplace of below line you can give below line in else part of positioin== 2 condition
convertView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.list_item_unSelectedImage);
         if(position == 2) {
             convertView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.list_item_selected);
         }


         return convertView;
     }
```

Comment: Wow.. such a simple solution... thanks!

I like @user3676184 idea of using an else with my if statement. Both methods work though =]